# É possível criar campos em relatório JasperReports sem defini-los previamente?

Tags: swing, jasper-reports

Olá, tenho uma `jTable` onde o usuário define quais campos aparecerão nela, desta forma eu precisaria de vários relatórios `JasperReports`, um para cada combinação possível (escolhida através de `jRadioButtons`).
Existe uma forma de "enviar" os campos do relatório(seus nomes) além dos parâmetros , sem criar os campos previamente no relatório `JasperReports`?

Print da JTable:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Aí é o seguinte, tem alguns `jRadioButtons` onde o usuário escolhe quais campos ele quer que apareça na `jTable`  (depois da jTable populada), por exemplo ele pode querer que apareça somente "código" e "nome".
Daí a necessidade de vários relatórios, com campos diferentes, campos estes que eu queria "enviar" e não te-los criados no relatório antecipadamente.
Estou tentando algo com `DynamicReports`, porém eu usava uma `HQl` para o relatório contendo a `jTable` completa , sem o usuário escolher o que quer visualizar, estou tentando adaptar o código .

Método que gera o relatório da `jTable` completa:

```
private void jBGerarRelatorioActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                 

        DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) jTableResultado.getModel();
        JRTableModelDataSource dataSource = new JRTableModelDataSource(model);

        String path = getClass().getResource("/relatorios/Teste.jrxml").getPath();
        JasperReport report = null;
        try {
            report = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(path);
        } catch (JRException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(ConsultasView1.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        Map<String, Object> parametros = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        JasperPrint jp = null;
        try {
            jp = JasperFillManager.fillReport(report, parametros, dataSource);
        } catch (JRException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(ConsultasView1.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        JasperViewer jrv = new JasperViewer(jp, false);
        jrv.setVisible(true);

    }
```

Evento do `jRadioButton`

```
 private void jRadioCodigoItemStateChanged(java.awt.event.ItemEvent evt) {                                              
        if (evt.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED) {
            jTableResultado.getColumnExt("Código").setVisible(false);
        } else if (evt.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.DESELECTED) {
            jTableResultado.getColumnExt("Código").setVisible(true);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Tem como você por um print da sua JTable pra mim visualizar e entender melhor seu problema?
De um exemplo do que vai exibir.

Comment: @Julio Cesar da Silva Barros, Acrescentei algumas informações.

Comment: Resolvi mudar a abordagem e fiz com http://www.dynamicreports.org/ , mas se alguém souber algo sobre fazer  com `Jasperreports`, gostaria de tentar.